# CSV Manipulation in python lists

Tags: python-2.7, list, csv

i have combined two lists using zip syntax. When i saved it in csv format, whole data are stayed in one cell of excell. what's that i want is:each element of zipped file should be stay on each row.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two lists, one containing some persons' names, the other one containing persons' ages. The following code can save the two lists into a csv file with "name" and "age" being two columns.

```
names = ["Alice","Bob","Cathy"]
ages = [10,20,30]
# use , to delimit columns
to_write = ["{},{}".format(names[i],ages[i]) for i in range(len(names))]
# write to a csv file
open("path/to/your_csv.csv","w").write("\n".join(to_write))
```

Comment: It have worked. Thank u